# How can i implement a NIO approach to serialports?

Tags: serial-port, netty, nio

OiO is deprecated in the current Netty version and all the serialport implementations i could find use this. 
Now i haven't been able to find any sort of guide on how to write your own channel so maybe i'm doing it all wrong.

I've tried starting from NioSocket but keep getting stuck on the Unsafe override...

Could someone tell me which base class i should extend to implement JserialComm or any other lib? Or point me in the direction of a decent howto?

Answer (score 0):

I am finding myself in the same boat. I have done work with both JSerialComm and PureJavaComm and benchmarked both their input/output stream performance and their OIO implementations I found on github. https://github.com/gsrunion/Java-Serial-Solution-Performance-Tests

Per the issue https://github.com/Ziver/Netty-Transport-jSerialComm/issues/2 I believe I am going to have to take an approach where I use Netty's EmbeddedChannel as a go between between a the input/output streams and a Netty stack.

Comment: In the end I didn't use Netty for the connection but JSerialcom instead, adapted the later stages of the data handling to work with it the same as would be done if it was a netty channel.

Comment: I found a JSerialComm -> Netty transport implementation. Though there were a couple nuances of JSerialComm that made it not play well with Netty.

Comment: I have a couple pull requests out on JSerialComm to address.